# delete gridview row Programmatically

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, webforms, delete-row

I keep returning an error when trying to delete a row in my gridview (Input string was not in a correct format)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

```
<asp:GridView ID="favoritesGrid" runat="server" OnRowDeleting ="favoritesGrid_RowDeleting">
    <columns>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FavoritesId" DataField="FavoritesId"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Site Name">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:HyperLink ID="myHyperlink"
                                Text='<%# Eval("SiteName") %>'
                                NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'
                                runat="server">

                 </asp:HyperLink>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </columns>
</asp:GridView>



   protected void favoritesGrid_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        var delId = Convert.ToInt32(favoritesGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
        //var id = favoritesGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
        var delFavorites = new FavoritesDb();
        var delFavs = delFavorites.DeleteFavorite(delId);
        DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Could you show exception that you get and point where it is thrown?

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. on the "var delId = Convert.ToInt32(favoritesGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell at position 0 has the word "delete" in it and it cannot be converted to int.
You need to use:

```
var delId = Convert.ToInt32(favoritesGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);
```

However, this is not a good approach since you might change the cells order or add a new one. You'd better use the DataKeyNames attribute.

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="FavoritesId" ...>
```

C#:

```
Convert.ToInt32(favoritesGrid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
```